# How to create mailboxes in Domino Server?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I want to create a mailbox for each user in a Domino server.
In order to maintain different mailboxes for different user.
And storing their respective mails in it.
example:

User: A
Mailbox: Amailbox storing mails of user A

Comment: Not programming related, belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: I presume the C# tag means he wants to do it programmatically in C#, therefore it becomes programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there already exist Person documents in the Name & Address Book (NAB) for the users, but the users do not have a mail database already, then you should be able to do this from C#, using the Notes/Domino COM classes.

For a given user, you will want to dop at least the following:

(1) create a new database (NSF) from the mail template. You can do this using the COM method CreateFromTemplate on the Database class. (You'll first get a handle to the mail template using the GetDatabase method on the Session class - the template filename will be mail8.ntf, or similar).

(2) add this user as a Manager in the ACL of the newly created database - you can do this using the ACL property of the Database object for the newly created database, and the CreateACLEntry method of the ACL class.

(3) add this new database's filepath to the Person document for this user, in the Name & Address Book. This will allow the mail router to find where to deposit new mail for the user.

Answer (score 1):

The Register User command in the Admin Client should be used when creating new users, this creates the mail file and id of the user.